# Finding mean/std of matrix-vector multiplication

Tags: machine-learning, probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, random-variable

I have some vector $x$, with mean $\mu_x$ and standard deviation $\sigma_x$, coming from an unknown distribution. I’d like to perform the linear transformation $y = Wx + b$, where $W$ is a matrix and $b$ a vector. I know everything about $W$ and $b$, however I’m only given $\mu_x$ and $\sigma_x$ (i.e., I don't have $x$'s individual values). Is it possible to obtain an expression for the output mean and standard deviation, $\mu_y$ and $\sigma_y$, using only $\mu_x, \sigma_x$ and any statistics from $W$ and $b$? If not, is there any other information can I include about $x$ to make this possible?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What is the relationship to machine learning? If there is some greater machine learning context in which this question has arises, it might be helpful to discuss that.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I didn't include anything here about ML, but specifically, I'm looking at instance normalization (IN) after a convolutional layer. From my question, let's just say "y" gets fed to an IN layer. For some complicated reasons, I'm not able to perform the on-the-fly normalization that IN requires when running stats aren't collected. However, I am able to provide statistics about "x", which could hopefully lead to statistics about "y" and therefore side-step this issue. Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Welcome to CV. The principle for finding the mean of $y$ is called "linearity of expectation."  It is invoked and explained a very large number of times here, so consider searching.  The slightly more difficult calculation is to find the covariance of $y.$  (The square roots of its diagonal elements will be the standard deviations of the components of $y,$ which must be a vector of the same size as $b.$) That principle is called *bilinearity.* The duplicate states this principle and provides some formulas.